# Нет изменений при вызове процедуры в WP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Есть такая часть кода, которая не работает

```
$email = strval(get_option( 'email_who_paid' ));
$amount = get_option( 'amount_paided' );
$period = get_option( 'license_duration' );
$date = strval(date("Y-m-d"));
$wpdb->query("CALL ExtendLicense( $email, $period, $amount, $date )");
$wpdb->query('COMMIT');
```

Если заменить две переменные на просто значение комит происходит

```
$email = strval(get_option( 'email_who_paid' ));
$amount = get_option( 'amount_paided' );
$period = get_option( 'license_duration' );
$date = strval(date("Y-m-d"));
$wpdb->query("CALL ExtendLicense( 'some@gmail.com', $period, $amount, '2018-02-02' )");
$wpdb->query('COMMIT');
```

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: *Что я делаю не правильно?* Вот ты вместо `$email` подставляешь `'some@gmail.com'`. А у тебя в переменной эти обрамляющие кавычки - есть?

Comment: Но переменная же строчного типа, они по автомату станут. Или нет?

Comment: Это с какого перепугу? Сделай по-человечески - сперва собери текст запроса в переменной, потом выполни его. А в промежутке - выведи, что у тебя в переменной получилось, чтобы видеть, а не ерунду ли пытаешься выполнить. А заодно - смотри статус выполнения запроса и выводи сообщения об ошибках, очень способствует.

Comment: Спасибо помогло)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$email = "'" . get_option( 'email_who_paid' )) . "'";